# Windows 7 x64 Cannot Copy Text in 32-bit Console

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, console

Every time I attempt to mark a selection in a 32-bit console application, the selection cursor becomes incredibly slow and I start getting beeps; the selection disappears once I let up on the left mouse-button, and there is no time to press Enter to capture the text to the clipboard.  64-bit console applications do not have this issue.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit.

Comment: Weird. You're not using a ps2 to usb adapter are you?

Comment: No, it's on the built-in keyboard on a laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try hitting <kbd>pause</kbd> key before you select something or you may be interested in trying another console https://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console

Comment: this can happen in console applications when they keep refreshing at high frequency like when updating values or drawing something and that key is designed just to freeze the window :)